# How to resize the height of an iframe when its content changes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to resize the height of an iframe when its content changes (when someone clicks on a link on the iframe), with no scroll. It means that the iframe should take the height it needs on the page.

I tried to use the function **onLoad** but it just works **the first time the iframe is loaded** (not when I click on an internal link inside the iframe).

The website embedded in the iframe is in React (is it a problem?). The iframe is embedded in a different domain name (I gave authorisations with Django CSP).

Do you know how to do it? Thanks a lot!

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onload="autoResize('iframe');" ></iframe>

<script language="JavaScript">
function autoResize(id){

    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem once. There is no automatic feature for iframes to adjust their height. You need to implement a manual form of communication of a height change between the main page (`window.onmessage`) and the embedded page (`parent.postMessage`).
The tutorial I used was [Medium: How to Automatically Resize an iframe](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-automatically-resize-an-iframe-7be6bfbb1214)
 and I was very happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed it, but the window.onmessage is always null. Are you sure this will work if the iframe is included in a different domain ?

I include the iframe <iframe src='example.com'></iframe> on the website my website.com

Comment: If both implement the code (both working together). So you kinda have to own the page you are embedding. Other sites don't tell you by default.

Comment: Communicating cross-domain in general is no problem with postMessage.